# Applying await to a task with a callback

Tags: c#, task

I have a Finite State Machine for a turn based game.

ProcessState checks for the current state and does something, then waits for a callback to be called

```
private void ProcessState(GameStatus status)
        {
            switch (status.CurrentState)
            {
                case State.START_TURN:
                    DoStartTurn(status, () =>
                    {
                        status.SetCurrentState(State.WAIT_MOVE); 
                    });
                    break;

                case State.WAIT_MOVE:
                    // ...
                    break;
            }
        }
```

The 'Do' functions emit an event and an external consumer will call the done eventually.

```
  private void DoStartTurn(GameStatus status, Action done)
        {
            OnStartTurn?.Invoke(status, done);
        }
```

Is there a way to transform the ProcessState in an async method to simplify the code?

I would like to have something as the following

```
case State.START_TURN:
   await DoStartTurn(status);
   status.SetCurrentState(State.WAIT_MOVE);
break;
```

My problem is to put together the Task concept to use async/await with the emitting event waiting for a callback.

Thanks!

Edit:

I try to provide the whole class (is a class for Unity but it is just a plain class)

```
using System;
using Sirenix.OdinInspector;
using UnityEngine;

namespace GenericCardEngine
{

    [ShowInInspector]
    public class Engine
    {
        [HideInInspector]
        public Action<GameStatus, Action> OnInit;
        [HideInInspector]
        public Action<GameStatus, Action> OnStartGame;
        [HideInInspector]
        public Action<GameStatus, Action> OnStartTurn;
        [HideInInspector]
        public Action<GameStatus, Action> OnReshuffle;
        [HideInInspector]
        public Action<GameStatus, Action<Move>> OnWaitMove;
        [HideInInspector]
        public Action<GameStatus, Action> OnInvalidMove;
        [HideInInspector]
        public Action<GameStatus, Action> OnEndTurn;
        [HideInInspector]
        public Action<GameStatus, Action> OnEndGame;

        [ShowInInspector]
        GameStatus gameStatus;
        
        public Engine(Config config)
        {
            gameStatus = new GameStatus(config);
        }

        public void Begin()
        {
            gameStatus.OnStateChange += ProcessState;
            ProcessState(gameStatus);
        }

        // Preferisco far ritornare o niente o la mossa dal consumer in modo da poter visualizzare l'intera FSM qui
        private void ProcessState(GameStatus status)
        {
            if (status.ShowDebugLog) Debug.Log($"Processing {status.CurrentState}");
            switch (status.CurrentState)
            {

                case State.INIT:
                    DoInit(status, () =>
                    {
                        status.SetCurrentState(State.START_GAME);
                    });
                    break;

                case State.START_GAME:
                    DoStartGame(status, () =>
                    {
                        status.SetCurrentState(State.START_TURN);
                    });
                    break;

                case State.START_TURN:
                    DoStartTurn(status, () =>
                    {
                        if (status.Deck.IsEmpty)
                        {
                            status.SetCurrentState(State.RESHUFFLE);
                            return;
                        }
                        status.SetCurrentState(State.WAIT_MOVE);
                    });
                    break;
                    
                case State.RESHUFFLE:
                    DoReshuffle(status, () =>
                    {
                        status.SetCurrentState(State.WAIT_MOVE);
                    });
                    break;

                case State.WAIT_MOVE:
                    DoWaitMove(status, (move) =>
                    {
                        MoveType type = Rules.ClassifyMove(status, move);

                        if (type == MoveType.VALID)
                        {
                            Rules.ApplyMove(status, move);
                            status.SetCurrentState(State.END_TURN);
                        }

                        if (type == MoveType.INVALID)
                        {
                            status.SetCurrentState(State.INVALID_MOVE);
                        }

                    });
                    break;

                case State.INVALID_MOVE:
                    DoInvalidMove(status, () =>
                    {
                        status.SetCurrentState(State.WAIT_MOVE);
                    });
                    break;

                case State.END_TURN:
                    DoEndTurn(status, () =>
                    {
                        status.SetCurrentState(State.START_TURN);
                    });
                    break;

                case State.END_GAME:
                    DoEndGame(status, () =>
                    {
                        status.SetCurrentState(State.EXIT);
                    });
                    break;

                case State.EXIT:
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void DoInit(GameStatus status, Action done)
        {
            OnInit?.Invoke(status, done);
        }

        private void DoStartGame(GameStatus status, Action done)
        {
            Rules.DealInitialCardsToPlayers(status);
            Rules.DealCardsToTable(status);

            OnStartGame?.Invoke(status, done);
        }

        private void DoStartTurn(GameStatus status, Action done)
        {
            status.Turn++;
            Rules.NextPlayer(status);
            Rules.DealCardsToPlayerForTurn(status);
            OnStartTurn?.Invoke(status, done);
        }

        private void DoReshuffle(GameStatus status, Action done)
        {
            Rules.Reshuffle(status);
            OnReshuffle?.Invoke(status, done);
        }

        private void DoWaitMove(GameStatus status, Action<Move> done)
        {
            OnWaitMove?.Invoke(status, done);
        }
        private void DoInvalidMove(GameStatus status, Action done)
        {
            OnInvalidMove(status, done);
        }
        private void DoEndTurn(GameStatus status, Action done)
        {
            OnEndTurn?.Invoke(status, done);
        }
        private void DoEndGame(GameStatus status, Action done)
        {
            OnEndGame?.Invoke(status, done);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: without more code, there's not much to tell. The code snippet you propose should do the job (in an async method).

Comment: @jeroenh my problem (i think) is not being able to write the DoStartTurn method, could you provide an example, please?

Comment: That somehow doesn't sound right. "Start Turn" sounds more like a state change trigger than a state in itself.

Comment: @Fildor I provided the whole class, maybe it's clearer. Thanks

Comment: Except for some cases, I do not see a good use case for using a task in a loop based application (i.e a game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that you require of the Engine clients to provide 'callbacks to callbacks'. It looks like the design could change by :

- changing the `Action` signatures to `Func<Task>`, so you can properly await those
- remove the callback from those signatures (and just call that logic inline)

Something like this:

```
class Engine
{
    // Func returning Task, so they can be awaited
    public Func<GameStatus, Task> OnInit;
    public Func<GameStatus, Task> OnStartGame;

    // make the ProcessState function async
    private async Task ProcessState(GameStatus status)
    {
        switch (status.CurrentState)
        {

            case State.INIT:
                // business logic for init game
                await DoInit(status);
                status.SetCurrentState(State.START_GAME);
                break;

            case State.START_GAME:
                await DoStartGame(status);
                status.SetCurrentState(State.START_TURN);
                break;
            // .. etc
         }
    }

    private async Task DoInit(GameStatus status)
    {
        await OnInit(status);
    }

    private async Task DoStartGame(GameStatus status)
    {
        Rules.DealInitialCardsToPlayers(status);
        Rules.DealCardsToTable(status);
        await OnStartGame(status);
    }

    // .. etc
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks! This worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a TaskCompletionSource to transform a callback to a task-based call:

```
Task DoStartTurn(GameStatus status)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        OnStartTurn?.Invoke(status, () => tcs.SetResult(true)));
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

The code would however be more elegant if the task-concept extended all the way down the call-chain. In your example it is not obvious if `DoStartTurn` actually does anything asynchronous. Or what happens if any exception occurs. Or what should happen if there is not exactly one listener to the event.

Comment: I think I was looking for something like that, I need to fully understand it before telling :)
Thanks.

I also provided the whole class maybe it's more useful for you guys.

DoStartTurn is asynchronous because the callback is called by a consumer in an asynchronous fashion.
There is only and only one consumer for each instance and I still need to implement error handling.

I'll study your comment, thanks a lot.